# Translation of haggadah section titles

Tags: hebrew, passover, passover-seder-hagada, translation

What are the litteral translations of the different section titles of the haggadah? (i.e. What exactly do kadesh, urchatz, etc. mean)

Comment: Note that while one particular set is popular today, historically there were dozens of mnemonics floating around to remind people how to organize their meals on Pesach night.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- *Kadesh* is the [masculine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_gender) [singular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_number) [imperative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_mood): make *kidush*! (or: sanctify!) It's also a bare infinitive.
- *Urchatz* or *r'chatz* is the masculine singular imperative: (and) wash!
- *Karpas* is a matter of much discussion, but it's some sort of vegetable.
- *Yachatz* is the masculine singular third-[person](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_person) future [tense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_tense) transitive: He will divide.
- *Magid* is the masculine singular present tense: I/you/he tells.
- *Rochtza* is an [non-finite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-finite_verb) form: wash/washing.
- *Motzi* is the masculine singular present tense: I/you/he removes.
- *Matza* is non-*chametz* bread.
- *Maror* is some kind of vegetable.
- *Korech* is the masculine singular present tense: I/you/he wraps.
- *Shulchan orech* is the masculine singular present tense: I/you/he sets a table. It could also mean "a table sets (something)" but that seems less likely.
- *Tzafun* is a [participle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Participle) (I think it's called; anyway, an adjective formed from a verb): hidden.
- *Barech* is the masculine singular imperative: bless! It's also a bare infinitive.
- *Halel* is the masculine singular imperative: praise! It's also a bare infinitive. It also seems to be a noun: praise.
- *Nirtza* is the masculine singular present or masculine singular third-person past tense: I am/he is/it is/you are/he was/it was accepted/wanted.

I'll leave the precise translation of *karpas* and *maror* to others.

Comment: And *motzi* is called such as it blesses G-d "Who brings bread out of the ground."

Comment: Would it not be Yahitz if it were future? I wonder if it derived from an Arabic construct that would be like wahatz or something in Arabic. It could br an infinitive. Truth is, I have no idea what it is or is supposed to be, but future just doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: I'm also not so sure about your translation of Shulhan 'Orech. I know how you came up with it, but I wonder if it's derived from an older expression that therefore has a form we're not as familiar with. I'm not calling your translation(s) wrong, but it just seems very odd to me that we'd have these titles that are grammatically unusual, to say the least. It's not like nobody knew how to speak Hebrew before Ben-Yehudah came around.

Comment: @SethJ, re _yachitz_, that's if it's _hif'il_. In _kal_ with root _ch-tz-h_ it would be _yachatz_ (with the dropped _he_ as is sometimes found in _Tanach_ or, as here, for rhyme or the like). I can't speak to Arabic. Re "it just seems very odd to me that we'd have these titles that are grammatically unusual, to say the least": I think it's meant to rhyme and fit a meter.

Comment: Hmm. When were the titles coined?

Comment: Bazinga! Never mind. [New question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14628/5)!