# Origin of Haggadah Section Titles (Kadesh Urchatz, etc.)

Tags: history, passover, passover-seder-hagada

What is the historical origin of the section titles of the Haggadah?

(Inspired by discussion in comments on [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/14605/5) to the question: [Translation of haggadah section titles](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14604/5))

Comment: I wonder whether it might be better to reword the question as "Origin of Kadesh Urchatz" or something similar, so it comes up better in Google searches.

Comment: @Alex, given my general transliteration scheme, I'm not sure it'll help, but let's see.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Machzor Vitry (sec. 65)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9377&pgnum=489) attributes them to Rashi. [This site](http://www.piyut.org.il/textual/690.html) says that it has also been attributed to R. Shmuel of Falaise, one of the Tosafists (mid-13th century), but that the true authorship is unknown.

(It was actually originally just one of a lot of mnemonics for the order of the Haggadah composed by various rishonim. Another one, from Maharam Rothenburg, is printed in Hagahos Maimonios in the standard editions of Rambam, end of Hil. Chametz Umatzah. R. M.M. Kasher's Haggadah Shleimah has these two plus a dozen or so others. Apparently this one won out because of its simplicity and brevity.)

Comment: Those are all Ashkenazi sources. Do the sephardim have a similar custom of listing the stages?

Comment: @DoubleAA Do or did?

Comment: @HodofHod Yes. ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: @DoubleAA Doesn't seem to be any section titles in the [Sarajevo Haggada](http://www.talmud.de/sarajevo/ansicht_1.htm). (post-Rashi, Sephardic). Not sure if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: @Alex, Wait, the Machzor Vitri (late 11th century) enumerates them and attributes them to Rashi, but that site claims they were written mid-13th century?

Comment: Anyone know why it's "Urchatz" and not "Rechitzah"?

Comment: @SethJ http://www.bnaiavraham.com/learning/weekly-parsha/kadesh-urchatz-why-the-extra-vav-2/

Comment: Anyone have a link to this Haggadah Sheleima?