# Washing hands during the Seder

Tags: passover, passover-seder-hagada

I'm curious about the name assigned to the 1st hand washing in the Seder, the one just after Kiddush. It is called ורחץ . This seems to translate as which seems to translate as "and wash".

The 2nd washing which occurs prior to eating Matzah is called רחצה meaning "washing". This is a noun form.

The 1st format seems to be a verb form and it also starts with a *vav* which implies that it is somehow connected to the Kiddush, just before it.

Why are there two forms for the two different washings (Would there be a problem or confusion if we called them both רחצה ? WHy is one a verb and the other a noun? And, is the 1st washing connected to the Kiddush - If so, how?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14604

Comment: @mbloch Thanks. I edited. I get confused, sometimes with the way this editor changes directions when there's a Hebrew word in the middle.

Comment: not response but a linke with your question if washing connected to Kiddush in Sefer Hachinuch (mitsva 21)
"""בתחלה מביאין מים ונוטלין יד אחת בשביל כוס של קדוש שצריכין לטל. והכי איתא בברכות בפרק כיצד מברכין, (מג, א) שבכוס מספיק נטילת יד אחת, ואין מברכין על נטילה זו. ואם רצה לטל שתי ידיו לכוס נוטל בלא ברכה. ואחר כך מברך על היין ומקדש ואינו מברך על היין לאחריו. ואחר כך נוטל שתי ידיו ומברך על נטילת ידים, ומטבל בירק (הירק בדפוס וילנא)"""

Comment: @kouty actually, that may be a partial answer, as I did ask that question. I think you should consider that and, if possible, translate or paraphrase the above. You should also provide a link, if possible.

Comment: I you want to read the  chinuch with a beautyfull and pashut perush see [this](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49219&st=&pgnum=45&hilite=)

Answer (score 1):

[andrewmh20](/users/2246/andrewmh20) [cites](/posts/57124/revisions) Likutei Taamim Uminhagin as saying that it is to allow the steps to rhyme:

> Kadesh **Urchatz**
>   Karpas **Yachatz**
>   Magid **Rochtza**
>   Motzi **Matza**

That doesn't explain the "and" *vav* on *urchatz*. I've no explanation for that (and hope someone else will post such), but note that some even modern-day *hagados* don't have the *vav*.

Comment: I'm not sure that that's the only reason or the main reason, either. The rhyme, also, is not there at the end - "Tzafun barech, Halel Nirtzah".

Comment: @DanF Many old versions had Tzafun Notel (ie נוטל mayim achronim), Barekh Hallel. (Nirtza isn't really a "step". Some old lists end with things like גמור or יצא at the end. It fills out the poem.)

Comment: @msh Perhaps the vav fills out the syllable (and the meter). R'chatz is in some sense only one syllable.

Comment: @DanF the end does rhyme. The rhyme scheme is "AABBCCCB", with _nirtza_ rhyming with _matza_ and _rochtza_ as "B".

Comment: kadesh urchats both in imperative form. Karpas broke the continuity, and magid & rachatsa are not verbs but names as Rachatsa.

Comment: @msh210 http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14390&st=&pgnum=84&hilite= quotes some who have רחץ twice so the rhyme scheme is AAACBBBC.

Comment: Alternatively, it ends צפון נוטל ברך הלל [נרצה]&rlm; in which case it's AABBCCDD[E]